# I handed in my notice after received a verbal job offer

Tags: job-offer, notice-period, career-switch

I realise that I have done something stupid. After three rounds of interviews, I was offered a job over the phone. I was thrilled and excited as this is my dream job and I made a LOT of efforts in preparing the interviews. During the interview, I told the company that my notice period is a month.

A week ago, the hiring manager called and said I got the job and told me the start date is exactly in a month’s time. The hiring manager said he wanted to let me know asap so that I can hand in my notice as quick as possible in order to start the new job on time. He also said this has definitely been confirmed so don’t worry. Here goes the stupid part – I handed in my notice on the very next day so everyone in the company knows I am leaving in a month. It has been a week I still haven’t received a written offer so I emailed the hiring manager at 10 am this morning and haven’t heard anything back after COB. I have read some posts online and see some verbal offers can be rescinded. I start getting worried now and regret what I have done. Should I tell the hiring manager that my status or is it going to look like I am putting too much pressure to him and maybe he is really just busy preparing the documents? What should I do next?

Comment: At any point in the conversation, were you ever promised a written offer? Did you ever ask for one? You seem worried that you haven't received one yet, but it's not clear (to me) that one was on the way.

Comment: When he called, he said the written one will be with me in the next couple of days. I was too excited to ask exactly how long but I thought it would be within a week or so.

Comment: I know this has nothing to do with the question but did you ever talk to your current boss to see if there's a possibility of you staying if something goes wrong with your new offer? I'm not saying there would be, but it's a good idea to know your options.

Comment: @Isaiah3015 No, I didn't as I didn't think things could go awry really.  My current boss really likes me and ask me to reconsider my decision when I handed in my notice. But I am not sure if he is just being polite or not.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Thank you, I hope so. Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Send an email to the hiring manager of the new job.  Ask, calmly and politely, if there's a timeline for when you should expect to receive the formal paperwork.

> Hello [Name],
>
> Just following up on our phone conversation the other day.  I have given notice to my former employer as requested.  My official end date will be [DATE].  I was just wondering about when I might expect to receive the formal paperwork for the job offer.  Please let me know if there's anything else I can do to facilitate the process.
>
> Thanks, Lily

Was it foolish to quit without a formal job offer?  Maybe.  It is said that verbal offers are worth the paper they're written on.

That being said, it's only been one or two days, so don't start panicking yet.  Paperwork can take time (one of the reasons one generally waits for it to be ready.)  If you do wind up "falling between two stools" and the verbal offer is rescinded / never followed up on, you can deal with that and learn a lesson from it for the future.  However, for the time being I'd just sit tight and hope for the best.  What's done is done.

Comment: Don't panic, but if you were interviewing with more than one company, continue doing so and maybe find a different job.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thanks for your advice, I haven't any other interviews going but will start looking for other positions just in case!